# Conversion math behind byte to int

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head on the math and conversion process of my code. I understand how it got to that sum but how come it turned negative?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    short numb1 = 30000, numb2 = 30000;
    short answer = (short)Add(numb1, numb2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", numb1, numb2, answer);
    NarrowingAttempt();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

static void NarrowingAttempt()
{
    byte myByte = 0;
    int myInt = 200;

    myByte = (byte)myInt;
    Console.WriteLine("Value of myByte: {0}", myByte);
}
```

This returns:

```
30000 + 30000 = -5536
```

Little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30000 + 30000 = 60000, but short can only represent -32768~32767 (-2^15 ~ 2^15 - 1)

So, overflow occurs, and returns 60000 - 65536(2^16) = -5536

You must understand that all values that you handle are actually binary form inside a computer.

A short type is represented with 16 bits, or 2 bytes.
30000 in binary form is 0111 0101 0011 0000, and
60000 in binary form is 1 1110 1010 0110 0000, and only the last 16 bits are used to represent a short value.

To understand transforming this binary value into a decimal value, you must have some knowledge about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement, but in short it turns to -5536.
65536 comes from the fact that multiples of 65536 (2^16) have at least 16 '0's at the end in binary form.

Comment: What's the (2*16) for?

Comment: It just means 65536 is 2 to the power of 16 (2^16, 2**16 etc..)